# django comments: how to prevent form errors from redirecting the user to the preview page?

Tags: python, django, django-contrib

Currently, django.contrib.comments sends the user to the preview page if there is any error on the form.

I am using comments in the context of a blog and I would much rather that the user stayed on the page they were on if something went wrong with the submission. As far as I can tell though, this is hard-coded in django.contrib.comments.views.comments.post_comment:

```
# If there are errors or if we requested a preview show the comment
if form.errors or preview:
    template_list = [
        "comments/%s_%s_preview.html" % tuple(str(model._meta).split(".")),
        "comments/%s_preview.html" % model._meta.app_label,
        "comments/preview.html",
    ]
    return render_to_response(
        template_list, {
            "comment" : form.data.get("comment", ""),
            "form" : form,
            "next": next,
        },
        RequestContext(request, {})
    )
```

Is there any way that I can change this behavior without changing the source code to django.contrib.comments?

Any pointer would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have two real options:

- Write your own view.  Possibly copy that view's code to get started.
- Patch that view to take an extra parameter, such as 'preview_on_errors' which defaults to True but can be overridden.  Contribute the patch back to Django so other people can benefit from it.

Comment: +1 for writing your own view that wraps the post_comment view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There's now a way to [customize the Comments app](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/custom/). Good luck!